# Where to upload video files? to have online video albums? To share them for WhatsAPP apps

Tags: applications, video, skype, whatsapp-messenger, video-recording

I am having lot of Video files which are my personal to give to my girl friend.
My girl friend personal video files are also to send to me.

Now both together, i want to keep them as Album, Which i need to upload to Google Drive or Microsoft Sky-drive or Drop-box.

Like Photo upload/share concept, is there Video upload/share apps in Android?

Which could also help me:

- While using, WhatsAPP, or Skype 
  i need to send my google drive videos to someone using send video?
  Is there any way in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs), [Dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) or [SkyDrive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.skydrive) to upload your Videos. I think though that the [YouTube](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube) app would be better, just remember to mark your video as "private". You can even set up an extra Google Account just for that which you can both use with the same password.

Comment: You don't need to if she just logs on to the same YouTube account. Or, you just go into the YouTube app, select the Video and touch "Share" (the icon where one dot is connected to tweo dots) and select WhatsApp.

Comment: NO NO - Did you used Picasa? In Android when you use Picasa you can have your pictures always available for sending as attachment using any other third party Apps. You method is not the answer to send video from remote location via attachment such as if i write email or chat or use skype on Android i cant browse those videos to send it over via file transfering method.

Comment: Then use Picasa. It can do Videos, too.